# Docker compose runs in one folder but not in another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minio

I am trying to run minio/minio docker container on windows.
Docker-compose worked fine in one folder where I was testing,
but then I moved it into the project sub folder and docker-compose fails.

Folder with docker-compose is empty.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./storage/minio:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: test1234
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: test1234
    command: server --address 0.0.0.0:9000 /data
```

I get a timeout message after some time. Docker Desktop app works fine, I can start minio.
But I would prefer to use compose.

Online it says it's related to using relative paths in the volume or using git or proxy. But it's not that

This is the error response I get

```
Creating docker_minio_1 ... error

ERROR: for docker_minio_1  Cannot create container for service minio: Post "http://unix/filesharing/share": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

ERROR: for minio  Cannot create container for service minio: Post "http://unix/filesharing/share": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Any ideas, I appreciate any info. Thank you

Comment: probably moving it broke the path in volumes

Comment: Yes I think you are write. I pruned all volumes and it started working. Weird

Comment: @djulb Please add the correct answer and mark this as answered.